# Unsure why I'm getting a null value

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I just started learning Java and I am creating a simple TCP application where an input will be entered by a user and this input will be sent from the client side to the server side. This will then be processed and the result will be sent back to the client.

Here are my codes:

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    
        int port = 23456;
        
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input command:");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
            pw.println(request);
            pw.flush();
            
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String header = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(header);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int port = 23456;
        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server is ready to receive command!");
            
            while(true)
            {
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                        
                InputStreamReader isr = new
                InputStreamReader(is);
                        
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                
                String command = br.readLine();
                String response = "";
                int val = 0;
                
                try 
                {
                    String[] arr = command.trim().split("\\s+");
                    String operator = arr[0];
                    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
                    int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
                    
                    if (operator.equals("add")) 
                    {
                        val = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                        response = "The add result is: " + String.valueOf(result);
                    } 
                    else if (operator.equals("subtract")) 
                    {
                        val = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                        response = "The substract result is: " + String.valueOf(result);
                    } 
                    else if (operator.equals("multiply")) 
                    {
                        val = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                        response = "The multiply result is: " + String.valueOf(result);
                    } 
                    else if (operator.equals("divide")) 
                    {
                        if (secondNumber != 0)
                        {
                            val = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                            response = "The multiply result is: " + String.valueOf(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response = "Error: Divided by zero exception";
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        response = "Error: Invalid command " + "\"" + operator + "\"";
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(command + " is not a number");
                }
                        
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
                pw.println(response);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run, I get a `null` as the output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to read [ask] and then actually _ask_ a question. I _assume_ you're asking about why you get `null` somewhere - but _where_? If you'd be the one to read that post without any additional knowledge, would you be able to understand what's being asked for?

Comment: @Thomas it literally says Null in the console without any reference to any line.

Comment: One observation though: when you execute this command:  System.out.println(command + " is not a number");` the response to the client would be an empty string, is that intended?

Comment: "it literally says Null in the console" - I assume you mean when you're executing `System.out.println(header);` which would mean `header` is `null`.

Comment: What you're also missing is a check for "Result: Invalid number of arguments" - check `arr.length` before trying to access the elements. Since you're sending a blank string to the server (one that only contains whitespace), your command will have too few arguments. Try to fix that and actually send something meaningful - it should work then.

Comment: Assuming you are sending a string with spaces only ( `String request = " "; )` your server code generates an array index out of bounds (trim reduces it to an empty string which split will return an array of length 1) (i.e. `arr[1]` )which is not caught so the program terminates which leads to the socket closing with no response - hence the `null` on receipt.